# Can't set headers after they are sent. in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express package of nodejs and I have written this function to send response for any generic API. Although it keeps giving error and I can't figure out why. status function sets response status so I don't know why this should happen

```
function ResponseHandler(response, respObj, resData) {

  var resp = {
    "message" : respObj.message,
    "data" : resData
  }

  response.status(respObj.code);
  response.json(resp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're sending the request back with the `.status(number)` and then try to send the status again with `.json(string)`. Chain your functions and only one response will be sent.

```
response.status(respObj.code).json(resp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the below format:

res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' });

Check the following link to know more details:
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Despite what the comments said the only real thing I changed was moving the app.use before everything else. This solved the issue.

Comment: This headers comply with CORS and allow us to server our response to any origin